# python dbf to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, dbf

I'm trying to make an dbf to mysql connector in python. So far i have got it to connect the mysql server and read the dbf file but when I run the program it shows that none of the data has replicated in the sql.

Heres my code so far.

```
from dbfpy import dbf
import MySQLdb

source = dbf.Dbf("foxpro.Dbf")

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "mydb")
cur = db.cursor()

for r in source:
    query = """INSERT mytb SET column1 = %s, column2 = %s, column3 = %s"""
    values = (r["column1"], r["column2"], r["column3"])
    print r["column1"], r["column2"], r["column3"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written the query to insert but you haven't `execute()`d it.

```
# since your `values` is already a tuple
cur.execute(query, values)

# otherwise can be written as...
cur.execute(query, (r["column1"], r["column2"], r["column3"]))
```